# In Reincarnated as a Slime, when Myulan is exploring Rimiru city, why did a dragonewt stop to stare at her?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYAsqsrvY2s&t=22s

Did he figure out Myulan was a Majin or something of that sort? This is season two close to the midway point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well about that those races of dragonewt's can sense powers if they focused on they're surroundings so he just found that there was a majin and was thinking maybe that she might be related to the other majin's in the vincity and he saw her confused but not as a threat that would destroy the magic in the surrounding.

For example take the dragonewts leader's sister she wanted to join as an assassin with a majin.

So they might be used to they're vibe and saw her with the same vibe.

Comment: "those races of dragonewt's can sense powers" - Is that based on the novel or fantasy in general?

Comment: @DavidHobs based on the novel actually they have these extra powers which is [link](https://tensura.fandom.com/wiki/Gabiru/Abilities_and_Gears) mentioned here you can refer this